# The "Project Management" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I see some questions tagged as "project-management".  Since that's the subject of the entire site isn't this tag somewhat redundant?

Comment: agree, just like the tag "programming" in stackoverflow

Comment: +1 I agree. Should be more specific e.g. methodology, managing people, managing schedules, etc.

Answer (score 7):

There should be a rule that the tagname cannot match the name of the site.  For instance, Programmers Stack Exchange shouldn't have a Programmers tag.  Area 51 shouldn't have an Area 51 tag.  Cooking shouldn't have a Cooking tag.  Automotive shouldn't have an Automotive tag.

The idea is that tags should represent a component of project management or a component of the site topic, and a subject cannot be a component of itself.

Comment: Yup.  I think this is something we can all agree on.  If you read most of those questions it's clear they are really addressing a sub-topic.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was redundant.  As soon as I noticed that I had unlocked edit rights, I removed the tag.  *Every* question here should be about PM, so there's no need to explicitly tag a question `project-management`.  Tags need to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  You're one of just a few users who can actually police the site at the moment as there are no moderators actively participating yet, other than [Robert Cartaino](http://pm.stackexchange.com/users/123/robert-cartaino).

Answer (score 1):

I did that on one of my questions but later decided that the actual question wasn't about project management but about roles, so I removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I asked essentially [the exact same question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/tag-cleanup-merges-and-synonyms/375#375) on the meta page for the sister Stack Exchange site for Board and Card Games.

Although we had a lot of discussion in the comments below, we were ultimately barking up the wrong tree. The right way to deal with this was [described by a SE guru in another answer](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/398/should-we-use-the-tag-delete-me-or-remove-this-tag/399#399): basically for this site, the [project-management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/project-management) tag should be blacklisted. I assume Jeff Atwood can fix this for us here just like he did over at B&CG.